# I Can't use Symfony Login when im using JWT Authentication - Symfony 3.4

Tags: api, symfony, authentication, symfony-3.4, lexikjwtauthbundle

i have a symfony project that manager `two` parties the `website` and the `ionic app` so when i installed `JWT Authentication` to get `token` for app the `Login Form in website not working` I don't know why?

This issue happening when i use `FOSUserBundle` also.

The Login form worked fine before i added JWT

#### Security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: UserBundle:User
                #property: username to login just with the username

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                username_parameter:       username
                password_parameter:       password
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
          # for the website
        - { path: ^/login , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/home , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
          # for the app
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }`
```

#### LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login" ,name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        $errors = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUserName = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('@User\Login\login.html.twig',array(
            'errors'=>$errors,
            'username'=>$lastUserName,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout" ,name="logout")
     */
    public function logoutAction(){}

}
```

#### Login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="panel panel-success" style="width: 500px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2>Login</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username : </label>
            <input type="text" name="_username" id="username" class="form-control" value="{{ username }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password : </label>
            <input type="password" name="_password" id="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn-info btn pull-right">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% if errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ errors.messageKey }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

#### routing.yml

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

The problem is when i try to login it retuns the same login page without any errors.

When i try `127.0.0.1:8000/api/login_check` in `Postman` i got the `Token`

Comment: You use JWT but in the same time you have a *classic* form for login? Do you want to keep both? I think that you'll have to keep 2 firewalls with different configurations to allow JWT and *classic* login for humans.

Comment: Yeah classic form for `Website and JWT for `Ionic`, how to make 2 firewalls? add another login in firewall in security or what?

Comment: Do your users will call the API directly? That's a bit strange IMHO. Does the login works from the Ionic app?

Comment: Simply make a webservice to check credentials and call it in controller ?!

Comment: when i user login_check i got the token so i thinks login for ionic will be work, right? and and about webservice i don't know how?